# Simplest way to plot time values from file in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, whence this simple question. I would like to plot the values of an input file that contains time values. The output image should contain a blue line (for rows where Dist is 09.0), and a red line (for rows where Dist is 04.0).

I managed to generate a graph by entering integer values directly into [`graph.r`](http://harding.edu/fmccown/r/), but now I want `graph.r` to get these values from `input.txt` instead, and to keep them formatted as time (h:mm:ss). Is this possible, or will I have to parse `input.txt` before feeding it to R?

---

## input.txt

```
Date(x) Dist  Time(y)
120926  09.0  1:54:42
121001  04.0  0:19:00
121202  04.0  0:18:53
121206  09.0  1:13:19
```

## graph.r

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Define the cars vector with 5 values
input <- 'path/to/input.txt'
nine <- file(input)              #how to parse it?
four <- c(3600, 12:00, 16, 4, 9) #this fails because of "12:00"

# Set output file type to png
png("output.png", width=320, height=240)

# Graph using blue points for Dist 9, and red for Dist 4.
plot(nine, type="o", col="blue")
plot(four, type="o", col="red")

# Output to file
dev.off()
```

## Sketch of desired result, minus x y labels and legend

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it.  You will need the graphics package for "as.POSIXct" and you will need to click on the plot in the location you would like the top corner of your legend once the locator line is executed.

```
data=read.table("input.txt",head=T)

library(graphics)
plot(data$Date.x.,as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.y.,format="%H:%M:%S")),type="n", xlab="Date",ylab="Time")
lines(data$Date.x.[data$Dist==4],as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.y.,format="%H:%M:%S"))[data$Dist==4],col="red")
lines(data$Date.x.[data$Dist==9],as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.y.,format="%H:%M:%S"))[data$Dist==9],col="blue")

leg=locator(1)
legend(leg,legend=c(4,9),col=c("red","blue"),lty=1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your second sentence. Why click? Is it not possible to do this non-interactively?

Comment: Yes, you do not need to use the locator() function to choose the spot for your legend but then you will need to supply x and y values manually.